Pool to postgresql nodejs
Perhaps someone has already encountered it and will be able to tell. Unfortunately, I could not find at least a small part of the information.
I know  can use third-party libraries, including pg, on which is created connecting pool.
I'm trying to figure out how to create a connection pool to postgresql and send queries to the database.
At the moment I am trying to create a socket, specified the port and the postgresql host, but for some reason a connection error is returned.
It may be need to specify the schema, database name, username and password when connecting. But unfortunately it is not clear how to use everything to connect.
Please tell me how establish a connection pool to postgresql and send a simple request to postgresql, without using third-party libraries such as pg, socket.io  etc.
import * as net from "net";

let client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(5432, 'localhost', () => {
  console.log('Connected');
  client.write('Hello');
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('error', err);
});

Connected
error Error: read ECONNRESET                                        
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}



Have you looked at the code of those third-party libraries to understand what they are doing?

"it is not clear how to use everything to connect" - you need to study and implement the Postgres protocol if you don't want to use a library to do it

Not clear why you are mentioning socket.io btw - it cannot connect to a Postgres database?

@Bergi yes, of course I looked at the source code, it didn't help much example, example 2. socket.io. Postgres protocol it does not contain the necessary information

The protocol does contain all the necessary information. Did you read the entire document? What exactly are you looking for? The startup flow with a StartupMessage? Not sure what you expected client.write('Hello'); to do.

@Bergi thanks, I'll read it again Postgres protocol. But i don't understand how the connection should be performed in node.js. Even if remove client.write('Hello'); there will still be a connection error.

You have to send the correct binary messages
